# Скачивание файла по http ссылке

Tags: php, guzzle

При переходе на определенную ссылку, например `site.ru/catalog`
происходит одновременное скачивание csv файла, и отражение раздела `/catalog` со статусом 404, хотя страница каталога отображается.

Каким образом можно скачать файл, который автоматически скачивается при переходе по ссылке?

Использую для этого `GuzzleHttp`:

```
$g = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $g->get("http://site.ru/catalog", [
    "sink" => "/files/file.csv",
]);
```

Выдает такую ошибку:
**Client error:** `GET site.ru/catalog` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
..

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://site.ru/catalog')` что получает?

Comment: @ArchDemon обнаружил проблему! Очень странное поведение. создал новый топик https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084393/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-php

Comment: В Guzzle можно выключать проверку https сертификатов. Это не очень хорошо, лучше подсовывать файлы с сертификатами. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1935 или https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066409/how-to-ignore-invalid-ssl-certificate-errors-in-guzzle-5